# Can a php file securely accept requests from ANY other domain / website?

Tags: php, web-services, unity-game-engine, cross-domain, unity-webgl

I hope this question isn't too general. I am unsure where to post for advice on this otherwise:

I have an HTML5 application living on a webpage (to be specific, it's a webGL game published from Unity3D). I want to check the URL the game runs from and if it doesn't match a pre-approved list of URLs, then it should "phone home" and ping a PHP file on my server, which would then record the referring URL, and possibly even email a daily summary of these referrers.

Example use-case: If someone copied the game and installed it on their own website without permission, then this would ping my server and record where the game is.

I know how to check the URL, I know how to call a URL, I know a CRON job will be necessary for the emailing, etc...

What I DON'T know and is the question here is: Is it even possible for the webGL game to silently call my own server from someone else's or will cross-domain security get in the way and block it? Or will it cause a prompt to pop up? Etc? I don't know much about this part and am trying to figure out who I will need to hire and the scope of this job. But if it's not even possible, I'd rather abandon the idea completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you enable CORS in your "PHP file" here is how:
https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

...you mentioned "phone home" **IF** your server is hosted on your home, make sure is accessible from the outside, you will need a static IP and to open the port(s) in the firewall if you have any.

And to answer your question: Yes it is possible to "phone home" silently. 
That is what analytics tools do, take a look:
https://unity3d.com/unity/features/analytics

Comment: Thank you. You make an excellent point about analytics (duh on my part!)

And no, I did not literally mean the server is in my home. "Phone home" is just an idiom. I meant contacting a website / server that would be under my control.